# Zeppelin 0.10.1 does not highlight according to code syntax

Tags: highlight, apache-zeppelin

```yaml
version: '3.2'

services:
  zeppelin:
    container_name: zeppelin
    image: apache/zeppelin:0.10.1
    network_mode: "host"
```

I use the latest zeppelin docker image to test zeppelin.

I open the notebook of `Spark Tutorial /3. Spark SQL (PySpark)`,
it is hightlight well.

but when I create a new paragraph in the notebook. the hightlight is not working.

[image: hightlight not working]

---

I open the notebook's zpln file in the disk and found the create paragraph's `editorSetting` is null

```
 "editorSetting": {}
```

and the hightlight working is like this

```json
        "editorSetting": {
          "language": "python",
          "editOnDblClick": false,
          "completionKey": "TAB",
          "completionSupport": true
        },
```

---

just don't know what do I miss make the highlight not working .